# express js - using passport to authorize in model

Tags: express, passport.js

I begin with express and pasport. I use MVC structure for my project.
in controller auth.js

```
members.authMember(username, password, function() {
            console.log('HERE')
        });
```

and in member_model.js

```
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
exports.authMember = function authMember(username, password, callback) {
    db.openConnection();
        passport.use(new LocalStrategy( function(username, password, done) {
            Members.find({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) {
                    // callback('Incorrect username.');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                }
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    // callback('Incorrect password.');
                    return done(null, true, { message: 'Incorrect password' });
                }
                // callback(user);
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }));
        callback();
    db.closeConnection();
}
```

After submit username and password using authMember function, my app does not response.
And commit to : 
https://github.com/ryantranvn/start
My problem is authorization with link : 
http://localhost:3000/admin/login

Thanks advances!

PS: username of member in DB is : admin

Comment: I'm assuming ` db.openConnection();` and `db.closeConnection();` are async. You can not run it and assume it is done when you execute them.

Comment: Thanks your reply! I will try it.